# QQ-Plot shifted up - interpretation and correction

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, bias

I am currently running a multi-linear regression (MLR) model on a dataset corresponding to the time consumed in production, from 2020 until 2022. I have done a fairly amount of investigation to drill down the variables used to 12 variables, non of them a time related variable (year, month, day, whatsoever). I am training the model in 1 year of data and test it on 5 months of data. All the assumptions of the MLR seem to be met, however, when I plot the qq-plot of the test residuals (y_test - y_predicted) I get almost perfect straight line but lying above the qq-plot line. The data seems normally distributed but is centered around 0.25-0.3.

[image]

I have tried to train and test the data in other time periods or with different test-train sizes (e.g. 5 months training set and 2 months test set) but such effects happen often, sometimes underestimating other times overestimating. Any idea of why this could happen, and how could this could be corrected? Is there any systematic method to tackle this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The mean of the residuals from the training set should be zero. Maybe you are using the test set? If so, it indicates systematic difference between the training and test data sets.

Comment: I am using the test set on the plot, the mean of the residuals in the training set is around zero as you set. I was just curious to know if there is any way of tackling the systematic difference between the training and test data sets.

Comment: Generating the sets randomly is standard practice. Seems like you are not doing that. Maybe there is some time trend or cycle that your model is not capturing correctly.

Comment: The problem of selecting the sets randomly is that the trainset and the test set will have data that is from the same period, since this is time series data it would be considered cheating. I should use a split based on time to avoid the look-ahead bias.

But I agree that there might be some time trends that the model is not capturing.